# Need to get empty Dropdown ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a web form and Dropdown Box. We can clone dropdown and can create some more. My problem is needs to know any of them are empty. My every dropdown id is begin with 'abcd'. 
For example

```
<select id='abcd_1'></select>
<select id='abcd_3'></select>
<select id='abcd_10'></select>
<select id='abcd_5'></select>
```

I tried following code but no luck

```
$( "input[id^='abcd']" ).val();
```

Comment: so want to each dropdown's id? there is not any value you trying to get

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/ `$("select[id^='abcd']:empty");` then use each or map

Comment: @RakeshSharma Yes needs to know all

Comment: you have more good answers for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if dropdowns are empty then you can use this:

```
   if( $( "select[id^='abcd']").has('option').length > 0 ) {
```

Because you have multiple dropdowns , you must repeat the code above with $.each:

```
$.each($( "select[id^='abcd']"), function(i, dropdown){
    if ($(dropdown).has('option').length == 0){
        alert($(dropdown).attr('id'));
    }
})
```

I made an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mihutz/M3FfZ/

Answer (score 8):

Try to use [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector to filter out the required elements,

```
var emptySelects = $( "select[id^='abcd']" ).filter(function(){ 
 return $(this).is(':empty'); 
});
```

or simply,

```
var emptySelects = $("select[id^='abcd']:empty");
```

And if you want to traverse it just use `.each()`

```
emptySelects.each(function(){
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('select').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('option').length == 0){
     alert($(this).attr('id'))   
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ef46w/)